# convert rtf to vcard (vcard code in rtf file)

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, vcard

This is sample of my rtf file

Ñ(,G_
Ñ(,G_

VERSION:2.1
REV:20071103T021433Z
N: ;;;;
END:VCARD
Ï(,G_
VERSION:2.1
REV:20070314T081620Z
N:KALMKARI;ABDUL
TEL;PREF;VOICE:+91989xxxxxx
END:VCARD
Ï(,G_
VERSION:2.1
REV:20070710T044836Z
N:;Abhi;;;
TEL;CELL:+9193xxxxx
END:VCARD

How can I convert this to vcard so that I can sync it with my mobile phone.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the file is a VCARD file that was saved as RTF.

You could try opening it in a word processor that can load RTF (such as OpenOffice.ort, MS Word, or MS Notepad), then save as "plain text" or "text".

If you're lucke, the resulting file will be a valid VCARD file.

If it still doesn't work, you'll probably have to fix it by hand (or write a script to fix it).

Out of curiosity: Where did the file come from? Who had the weird idea to save VCARD as RTF?